# SQL Server licensing in a virtualised environment

Tags: vmware, license, sql

My company has 6 instances of SQL Server 2012 Standard. These instances all run on VMware virtual machines. The licenses for SQL Server came packaged with WonderWare products ([WonderWare Historian](http://software.schneider-electric.com/products/wonderware/production-information-management/historian/) for example). In addition to the SQL Server licenses, WonderWare sells SQL Server Client Access Licenses so clients can 'legally' access the database(s).

So, our virtual machines are licensed with a server license and our clients are licensed with a CAL. Now, none of the SQL Server licenses that came with the WonderWare products we are using are covered by SA; They simply do not offer this option (or at least, they haven't offered it to us in any case).

We use VMware and have enabled features like DRS and HA. These features will automatically migrate a running virtual machine from one physical host to another. Microsoft states that you can assign a SQL Server licensed to another 'server' but only after a period of 90 days. My source for this is the following document: [SQL Server 2014 licensing guide (PDF)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=230678)

It states on page 20:

> SQL Server licenses that are not covered with active SA can only be reassigned to a different server within a server farm once every 90 days [...].

and:

> All SQL Server licenses with active SA can be reassigned to another server within the server farm as often as needed [...].

Does migrating a virtual machine (or virtual operating system environment) from one physical host to another qualify as moving a license from one server to another? In other words, am I violating the terms of my license agreement by using DRS and HA?

Comment: Please take a look here: [Where can I ask about Software Licenses/Licensing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165980/201151) and [What is the place to ask about legal issues associated with using software?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5908/what-is-the-place-to-ask-about-legal-issues-associated-with-using-software)

Answer (score 0):

Without SA, you lose VM Mobility. Brent Ozar gave a good breakdown on licensing here - http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/sql-server-2014-licensing-changes/